# Is there a way to print a final message in gnu make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a gnu make target to build with profiling information. I would like to print instructions to the user how to generate the coverage report when make has finished, that is after the last line of output from make.

Example:

```
$ make coverage
/usr/bin/g++ --coverage ....
...
make[1]: Leaving directory
<I want to print instructions here!>
$
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? How?

Comment: What's stopping you from adding an extra line to the target recipe such as `@echo whatever`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an `@echo` statement at the end of your tasks. Like this:

```
coverage:
    # do your stuff
    @echo foo bar

$ make coverage
foo bar
$
```